# jQuery Code After window.setTimeout Not Working

Tags: jquery

I have the following elements:

**Tiles:**
allTile
hotTile
mmyTile

**Sections:**
allSec
hotSec
mmySec

Example of what I want done:
If allTile is clicked, add the classes animated and bounceOut to all 3 sections to animate them out. Then remove those classes and add hide-me to hide them. After they're all hidden, then unhide allSec (since allTile was the selected tile) by removing hide-me and bounce it in by adding the classes animated and bounceIn.

Issue I'm facing:
After the first window.setTimeout, no code runs. However, if I put it in the console, it works fine. But if I post the entire function in the console, again it doesn't run the code after that window.setTimeout.

http://www.jsfiddle.net/met920/zt9eD
There should also be a CSS link to Animate.css from daneden.github.io/animate.css

Alternatively, here's the relevant code:

```
function(){
    animationClick('#allTile');
    animationClick('#hotTile');
    animationClick('#mmyTile');

    function animationClick(element){
        clickedEl = $(element);
        element = $(element.substring(0,4) + 'Sec');
        clickedEl.click(
            function(){
                //bounce out everything
                $(allSec).addClass('animated bounceOut');
                $(hotSec).addClass('animated bounceOut');
                $(mmySec).addClass('animated bounceOut');

                //wait for animation to finish
                //before removing classes and hiding them
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    $(allSec).removeClass('animated bounceOut');
                    $(hotSec).removeClass('animated bounceOut');
                    $(mmySec).removeClass('animated bounceOut');


                    $(allSec).addClass('hide-me');
                    $(hotSec).addClass('hide-me');
                    $(mmySec).addClass('hide-me');
                }, 2000);

                //bounce in the new one
                element.removeClass('hide-me');
                element.addClass('animated bounceIn');
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    element.removeClass('animated bounceIn');
                }, 2000);

            }
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: post html also,provide jsfiddle

Comment: try $("element").removeClass("animated bounceIn"); at the end

Comment: @PratikJoshi http://jsfiddle.net/met920/zt9eD/ there should also be a CSS link to Animate.css from http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: @PratikJoshi I tried $("element"). I even tried directly writing the element like $(allSec).removeClass, but even that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. The issue is that the code after the setTimeout happens before that timeout is over and since I'm adding and removing stuff, the hide-me tag was "removed" before it was added, keeping the tag there at the end.

```
function(){
    animationClick('#allTile');
    animationClick('#hotTile');
    animationClick('#mmyTile');

    function animationClick(element){
        clickedEl = $(element);
        element = $(element.substring(0,4) + 'Sec');
        clickedEl.click(
            function(){
                //bounce out everything
                $(allSec).addClass('animated bounceOut');
                $(hotSec).addClass('animated bounceOut');
                $(mmySec).addClass('animated bounceOut');

                //wait for animation to finish
                //before removing classes and hiding them
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(allSec).removeClass('animated bounceOut');
                    $(hotSec).removeClass('animated bounceOut');
                    $(mmySec).removeClass('animated bounceOut');


                    $(allSec).addClass('hide-me');
                    $(hotSec).addClass('hide-me');
                    $(mmySec).addClass('hide-me');


                    element.removeClass('hide-me');
                    element.addClass('animated bounceIn');
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        element.removeClass('animated bounceIn');
                    }, 2000);
                }, 1000);
            }
        );
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this it's work :**

```
function(){
    animationClick('#allTile');
    animationClick('#hotTile');
    animationClick('#mmyTile');

    function animationClick(element){
        clickedEl = $(element);
        element = $(element.substring(0,4) + 'Sec');
        clickedEl.click(
            function(){
                //bounce out everything
                $(allSec).addClass('animated bounceOut');
                $(hotSec).addClass('animated bounceOut');
                $(mmySec).addClass('animated bounceOut');

                //wait for animation to finish
                //before removing classes and hiding them
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(allSec).removeClass('animated bounceOut');
                    $(hotSec).removeClass('animated bounceOut');
                    $(mmySec).removeClass('animated bounceOut');


                    $(allSec).addClass('hide-me');
                    $(hotSec).addClass('hide-me');
                    $(mmySec).addClass('hide-me');
                }, 2000);

                //bounce in the new one
                element.removeClass('hide-me');
                element.addClass('animated bounceIn');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    element.removeClass('animated bounceIn');
                }, 2000);

            }
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: The only change is removing window. from window.setTimeout, right? If so, it works exactly the same.